# Acumatica - Making field required at graph level

Tags: acumatica

Hi I am stuck at a very basic requirement, where I have to make this field required at screen level. Below is the Original attributes for that field.

Field Name : `ExpirationDate`

Data Class  : `PX.Objects.CR.CRQuote`

Original Attributes:

```
     [PXDBDate(BqlField = typeof(Standalone.CRQuote.expirationDate))]
    [PXMassUpdatableField]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Expiration Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
```

I tried this by using CustomAttribute for both Required and Default :

```
 [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
 [PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXUIFieldAttribute), "Required", true)]
 protected virtual void CRQuote_ExpirationDate_CacheAttached(PXCache cache){}
```

and

```
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    protected virtual void CRQuote_ExpirationDate_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }
```

but still the form is allowing blank values. Please note field is a datetime type.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the first thing I noticed, but it may play a role in why you aren't getting the behavior you expect.  *BqlField =* indicates that this is a field of a projection.  I'm not sure that should matter, but in all honesty, I would have expected your PXDefault attribute to do the trick.

There are several ways to do this, but if you want it at the graph level then you are on track with PXMergeAttributes in either your custom graph or your graph extension.  Here are a couple of options you can try.

Conditionally Required:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<Condition or just True>))]
protected virtual void CRQuote_ExpirationDate_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{
}
```

Always Required:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXDefault]  // Notice the lack of PersistingCheck
protected virtual void CRQuote_ExpirationDate_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{
}
```

In the PXDefault example, you were sooo close to what I do.  I stick to no PersistingCheck or I use PXPersistingCheck.Nothing when I want to give a default but not make the field required.  Maybe there is some issue between it being a projection, a date field, and your persisting check option.  Also, since you are merging attributes, it's possible that some other code has a conflicting PXDefault attribute.

If none of that works, you might try just replacing the attributes entirely.

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXDBDate(BqlField = typeof(Standalone.CRQuote.expirationDate))]
[PXMassUpdatableField]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Expiration Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
protected virtual void CRQuote_ExpirationDate_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{
}
```

Last ditch effort, you can modify the projection and apply your modification to just your graph.  PXSubstitute will let you either globally have your projection replace the existing one or only replace in graphs you specify.  You would need to work out the specifics for your field and projection, but it would look something like this:

```
[Serializable]
[PXSubstitute(typeof(MyGraph)]
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<SOLineSplit,
    InnerJoin<SOLine, On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderType>,
            And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>,
            And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.lineNbr>>>>,
        InnerJoin<SOOrder, On<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderType>,
            And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>>>,
        InnerJoin<Contact, On<Contact.contactID, Equal<SOOrderExt.usrCUSTRequesterID>>>
        >>>),
    new Type[] { typeof(SOLineSplit) })]
public partial class SOLineSplit3Ext : POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3
{
    [PXDBString(BqlField = typeof(Contact.displayName))]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Requester", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual string UsrCUSTRequester { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrCUSTRequester : BqlType<IBqlString, string>.Field<usrCUSTRequester> { }
}
```